# ¿Obtener big-endian de un string?

Tags: c#, string

Tengo un `string` "730C" y necesito obtener un `INT big-endian`

```
string packetString = "1F:73:0C:01:00:0E:01:01:29:35:1D:00:02:00:01:00:00:00:E7:03:0B:00:65:73:74:65:73:69:74:72:61:62:61:02:01:00:00:00:00";

        string ChrIndx = packetString.Substring(3, 5);
        string chrinx = ChrIndx.Replace(":", "");

        // convertimos el texto a numero
        int num = Int32.Parse(chrinx, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        //Console.WriteLine(num);

        //// Int a Byte
        byte[] byteNumero = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);

        ////Pasamos de little a Big endian
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(byteNumero); //reverse 
        int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteNumero, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: @Elenasys no logro hacer la conversion =/ sume mas informacion para que podamos trabajarlo

Comment: porque no cambias el short.Parse() por Convert.ToInt32(chrinx, 16); como puse en el ejemplo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Me sigue dando, ahí acabo de adicionar. Pero no hace el reverse a big endian.

Comment: una duda, conoces como deberia ser el resultado que deberias obtener como big endian ? porque dices que tiene que aplicar el reverse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una forma de resolver mi problema! A continuación el codigo.

```
string packetString = "1F:73:0C:01:00:0E:01:01:29:35:1D:00:02:00:01:00:00:00:E7:03:0B:00:65:73:74:65:73:69:74:72:61:62:61:02:01:00:00:00:00";

        string ChrIndx = packetString.Substring(3, 5);
        string chrinx = ChrIndx.Replace(":", "");

        // convertimos el texto a numero
        int num = Int32.Parse(chrinx, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

            // Int a Byte
            byte[] byteNumero = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);

            //Pasamos de little a Big endian
            if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(byteNumero); //reverse 
            int result = BitConverter.ToUInt16(byteNumero, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: por eso te comentaba de aplicar el reverse, eso es lo que se comenta el link del msdn de la clase BitConverter

Answer (score -2):

Podrias analizar la clase

[BitConverter (Clase)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

usando algo como ser

```
    int number = Convert.ToInt32("730C", 16);
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);

    int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[convert string of hex to string of little endian in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637950/convert-string-of-hex-to-string-of-little-endian-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Leandro, creo que desea el Big Endian, saludos.

Comment: no soy un experto en el tema pero pude enteder que existe el BitConverter.IsLittleEndian, quizas deba validarse y aplicar el reverse de byte[]

Comment: Lo que comentas es lo que haría yo convertir a little Endian y a partir de ese valor convertir a Big Endian! *con un reverse de byte array.

Comment: Cuando intento aplicar el codigo me sale   An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

Comment: Acabo de adicionar mas informacion en mi pregunta inicial.